# Excel OleDb Data Types

Tags: excel, oledb

Does anyone have a list of data types I can use in a CREATE TABLE statement for Excel? I have searched and cannot come up with anything; at least not anything official. From one place, I found:

```
CHAR(255)
MEMO
INT
DATE
TIME
```

What about other numeric types? DECIMAL, etc? DATETIME (together)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Running this command:  DataTable schema = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Provider_Types, null); I get the following list:
`Short
Long
Single
Double
Currency
DateTime
Bit
Byte
GUID
BigBinary
LongBinary
VarBinary
LongText
VarChar
Decimal` Would this be what I want then?

Answer (score 4):

Be careful: Excel natively supports only the the following data types (so any other data type will be converted to one of these)

Double precision floating point (this handles integers, longs, dates,    times, currency etc) 
string 
Boolean
 Error

These data types can be formatted by the Excel renderer to look like currency, integer, date time etc.

Comment: Appreciate the info, Charles. Very helpful. However, it doesn't answer my question exactly. I really need to have a list of types acceptable to the OleDb connection to be used in a CREATE TABLE statement. When I get back to that project again, I think I'll have to give it a bit of trial and error, as I cannot seem to find any documentation on the matter. Thanks anyway. Appreciate the reply.